# What does the save() method of form actually do?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am watching a django tutorial and in it this code is used:

```
class UserFormView(View):
    form_class=UserForm

    def post(self:request):
        form=self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save()
            username=form.cleaned_data('username')
            password=form.cleaned_data('password')
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
```

In the tutorial it is said that the form.save() command stores the field data to the shell, which i find incredibly misleading. Shouldn't the save command save the data to a user object in the database? Next they use set_password to save the password value, what does `set_password` do? Does it hash the password input?

Finally the user details are persisted to the database by calling `save()` on user. But how does django know which model user belongs too? Is that information also acquired when you call form.save() and assign the result to `user` ?

Thank you

Comment: For a `ModelForm`, it saves the instance to the database, and returns it.

Comment: ok so user contains a persisted user object after the line `user=form.save()` ?

Comment: Bad tutorial. Whoever wrote this has no business doing "tutorials" and should better learn to properly use Django first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIY, you've got indentation problem in your code (or it's just as formatting). `form.save()` purpose is to save related model to database, you are right.

You're also right about `set_password`, for more info just [read the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password).

Django knows about model and all it's data, due to instance it's holding (in your case `user`). This data is available from that instance - [see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/meta/).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where this "tutorial" comes from but it's about as bad and wrong as it could be.

Assuming `UserForm` is a (correctly written) `ModelForm` (you didn't post the form's definition), `form.save()` should already take care of doing the right thing (creating the record in the database, with the password already encrypted, and returning the newly created `User` instance).

My advice: forget about this s...y tutorial, do the official one instead, and use the official doc for more details.

Comment: Seen it. OMG :facepalm: